# Postgresql partitioning and FK

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, partitioning

Currently have 2 database tables `sessionaccounting` and `sessionaccountingdailysplit`.

Each of these tables have data in them.
Sessionaccountingdailysplit has a FK constraint to sessionaccounting.

I need to partition both tables so that the final structure looks like this:

```
sessionaccounting
sessionaccounting2007
sessionaccounting2008
sessionaccounting2009
sessionaccounting2010
sessionaccounting2011
sessionaccounting2012
sessionaccountingdailysplit
sessionaccountingdailysplit2009
sessionaccountingdailysplit2010
sessionaccountingdailysplit2011
sessionaccountingdailysplit2012
```

Reason `sessionaccountingdailysplit` starts at 2009 is thats when the table was created

The process I followed to do the above is as follows:

1. I created the partitions for sessionaccounting based on a starttime
2. I created the partitions for sessionaccountingdailysplit based on a date
3. I created the constraint `CONSTRAINT sessionaccountingdailysplit2009_sessionaccountingid_fkey FOREIGN KEY (sessionaccountingid) REFERENCES sessionaccounting2009 (id) MATCH SIMPLE`

The above seems like it would work but due to the nature of how the dailysplit works its does not. How does dailysplit work? It takes the starttime and endtime from sessionaccounting and splits the data into individual rows.

So if I had a session that is from 2009-01-01 23:30:00 to 2009-01-03 13:00:00 the dailysplit creates 3 rows with each date in it so 2009-01-01, 2009-01-02, 2009-01-03.

Now with the above FK this would work because i know the partitioned year that the rows must go into. The problem comes when I have the following scenario of 2009-12-31 to 2010-01-01.

Since the sessionaccounting row is in `sessionaccounting2009` the FK works as `sessionaccountingdailysplit2009` has a FK to `sessionaccounting2009` but when postgres tries to insert the new row into `sessionaccountingdailysplit2010` it cant find the FK to `sessionaccounting2010` as its in `sessionaccounting2009`.

What I need help with is to make a rule or trigger that will insert data into the `sessionaccountingdailysplit2009` even though the rows date is 2010. So insert into `sessionaccountingdailysplit` table where it corresponds to which table the sessionaccounting row is in as to not violate fk constraints.

Is this possible?

A visual example

```
sessionaccounting2009
1, starttime:2009-12-31, endtime:2010
```

What I want

```
sessionaccountingdailysplit2009
1, date:2009-12-31
2, date:2010-01-01
```

What I get (this violates the FK in 2010)

```
sessionaccountingdailysplit2009
1, date:2009-12-31

sessionaccountingdailysplit2010
1, date:2010-01-01
```

The rule I use when inserting data but is causing the problem

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE sessionaccountingdailysplit2009_insert AS
   ON INSERT TO sessionaccountingdailysplit
   WHERE new.date >= '2009-01-01 00:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone
     AND new.date < '2010-01-01 00:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone
   DO INSTEAD
   INSERT INTO sessionaccountingdailysplit2009
     (id, sessionaccountingid, date, inputoctets
     , outputoctets, privcreditsused, usercreditsused) 
   VALUES (new.id, new.sessionaccountingid, new.date, new.inputoctets
          ,new.outputoctets, new.privcreditsused, new.usercreditsused
          )
   ;
```

Any help to sort out this?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that `sessionaccountingYEAR` tables are children of `sessionaccounting`. If that is true than you could just reference the parent table in instead of refer to the corresponding YEAR table:

```
CONSTRAINT sessionaccountingdailysplit2009_sessionaccountingid_fkey 
FOREIGN KEY (sessionaccountingid) 
REFERENCES sessionaccounting (id) 
MATCH SIMPLE
```

If `sessionaccountingYEAR` are not the children of `sessionaccounting`, could you explain why aren't they?